# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 (PHP build)

Tags: php, build, compilation

I have an interesting task: to create a php installation package.

Here is my install script:

```
./configure \
    --enable-pdo \
    --with-pdo-mysql \
    --with-mysql \
    --with-mysqli \
    --enable-mbstring \
    --with-curl \
    --with-gd \
    --with-mcrypt \
    --with-wpx-dir \
    --with-jpeg-dir \
    --with-png-dir \
    --with-freetype-dir \
    --with-xmp-dir \
    --with-zlib-dir \
    --with-openssl \
    --with-pear \
    --with-iconv=$(tea --prefix)/gnu.org/libiconv/v*
make
make install
```

At the final stage of the build I get the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_php_addslashes", referenced from:
      _php_filter_add_slashes in sanitizing_filters.o
      _zif_addslashes in string.o
      _zif_stream_socket_client in streamsfuncs.o
     (maybe you meant: _php_addslashes_sse42, _php_addslashes_default )
  "_php_base64_decode_ex", referenced from:
      _php_base64_decode in openssl.o
      _php_base64_decode in iconv.o
      _zif_base64_decode in base64.o
      _php_base64_decode in main.o
      _php_stream_url_wrap_rfc2397 in memory.o
     (maybe you meant: _php_base64_decode_ex_avx2, _php_base64_decode_ex_default , _php_base64_decode_ex_ssse3 )
  "_php_base64_encode", referenced from:
      _php_openssl_encrypt in openssl.o
      __php_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _zif_base64_encode in base64.o
      _php_stream_url_wrap_http_ex in http_fopen_wrapper.o
      _php_password_salt_to64 in password.o
     (maybe you meant: _php_base64_encode_default, _php_base64_encode_ssse3 , _php_base64_encode_avx2 )
  "_php_stripslashes", referenced from:
      _zif_stripslashes in string.o
     (maybe you meant: _php_stripslashes_sse42, _php_stripslashes_default )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

I can't deal with this at all. Maybe someone faced similar?

UPD: on another system:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_add_history", referenced from:
      _phpdbg_read_input in phpdbg_cmd.o
  "_readline", referenced from:
      _phpdbg_read_input in phpdbg_cmd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```